# Android loading contact images with UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android

In my app iam trying to load the contact images using UniversaImageLoader, i ran into few problems, and have few queries
1) Eventhough when iam running the Uniimagloader alone on my phone iam  getting the list but no images,
   what am i doing wrong?
2) i used some of the code from that proj , and also loaded the jarfile but still iam getting folloing error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152):    at org.app.activity.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:11)
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152):    at org.app.activity.ProfileActivity.<init>(ProfileActivity.java:39)
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
12-19 20:37:22.050: E/AndroidRuntime(10152):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
```

3) configuration for ImageLoader : iam doing this in my adapter , can i do that? doing this iam getting error at `maxImageWidthForMemoryCache(800)` it says Add cast to method reciever.

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                    .maxImageWidthForMemoryCache(800)
                    .maxImageHeightForMemoryCache(800)
                    .httpConnectTimeout(5000)
                    .httpReadTimeout(30000)
                    .threadPoolSize(5)
                    .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                    .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2000000))  
                    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))  
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
                    .build();
```

I am struck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make sure that context variable is an Activity instance. It has this kind of error in the past.